# Mysql join with subquery join with use of correlation names

Tags: mysql, join

I trying to use MySQL join with sub-query , sub-query also has join so i am facing problem,Please be kind, because i am not asking without trying, i tried my best to solve but getting syntax error this is because of correlation names t1 and t2

```
SELECT min(user_org.oid) as id, user_org_profiles.name from user_org
LEFT JOIN user_org_profiles ON (user_org.oid = user_org_profiles.oid) t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT user_org_profiles.name, max(user_org.gid) as gid
     FROM user_org LEFT JOIN user_org_profiles USING(oid)
     WHERE user_org.gid IN (1,2]) AND active =1 
     group by name) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.gid = t2.gid group by t1.name
```

getiing this error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ']) AND active =1 group by name) ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.gid = t2.' at line 6

Comment: Can you provide error details produced by your query

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid i edited

Comment: Alias on users_org_profiles should be right after the table name.

Comment: You also have a weird bracket in `(1,2])`.

Comment: `SELECT min(user_org.oid) as id, t1.name from user_org
LEFT JOIN user_org_profiles t1 ON user_org.oid = t1.oid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed problems with aliasing of `user_org_profiles` as `t1` plus a small typo in the `IN` list. Those mistakes were not very close to the text reported in the message though.

```
SELECT min(user_org.oid) as id, t1.name from user_org
LEFT JOIN user_org_profiles t1 ON (user_org.oid = t1.oid)
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT user_org_profiles.name, max(user_org.gid) as gid
     FROM user_org LEFT JOIN user_org_profiles USING(oid)
     WHERE user_org.gid IN (1,2) AND active = 1 
     group by name) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.gid = t2.gid group by t1.name
```

Comment: now getting error #1054 - Unknown column 'user_org_profiles.oid' in 'on clause'

Comment: I had changed that in my comment above but it didn't make it's way down to my answer. You have to refer to the table by alias after you alias it.